# R Shiny: View the logfile and update it with new entries

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R and certainly very new to RShiny.

I wrote a packages which logs events into a log file. Rstudio is capable of viewing live logging unitl the file is 5MB. So now i am thinking about writing a Rshiny app that views the logs as they are being written to the file.

Which functions would help me to update the viewer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`invalidateLater`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/invalidateLater.html) inside a `reactive` when you import the data. Data will be refreshed every time `invalidateLater` will fire (in my case every second).

Here a really silly example (my .csv doesn't update, it just prints that data is being refreshed to console):

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # mtcars.csv will be read every second
  mtcars_df <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    read.csv("mtcars.csv")
  })
  
  # mtcars_df is a reactive, hence will force the table to re-render
  output$data <- renderTable({
    print(paste("Table refreshed at", Sys.time(), collapse = " "))
    mtcars_df()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I will update you in few days. Thank you for suggestion!

Comment: @sveer Did this eventually work out for you?

Comment: I tried but not with 100% efforts to be honest and got busy with other stuff.